# Scrape to download file

Tags: screen-scraping

I have a website which contains some data and some hyperlinks to view the pdf documents. I have to create a application which can download that file using scraping and store it internally. How is it possible to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use any scraping library to do with that. Get the file url and download it.
[Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is an example

Comment: Thank you! for your help, my actual website has view document button upon clicking on it views the document in pdf viewer using a javascript method. So, I can click that button using scraping but how can I save that on my local file drive?